# How to match two dfs by a values (not joining) in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames. I want to juxtopose them and choose only those rows that are in the second data frame.

Sample data:

```
d1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,222,3,44,56,7,8,9,10,12,13,14),
             vals = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))

d2 <- data.frame(id = c(222, 56, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14),
             sum = c(12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 16, 16))
```

Desirable output:

```
  d3 <- data.frame(id = c(222, 56, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14),
                  vals = c(2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12))

  d3
     id vals
  1 222    2
  2  56    5
  3   7    6
  4   8    7
  5  12   10
  6  13   11
  7  14   12
```

I tried using `%in%` operator, but it does not work properly - sometimes it takes ids that do not appear in d2.

P.S. Some context. This is a sample data and example; originally I have a summarised table (`summarise()`) with sums of absolute values from original data frame. From the summarised table I've deleted all sums that equal 0. I need all non-zero value rows remain in my, so to speak, original data frame, so, I am comparing my two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Code
d3 <- d1[d1$id %in% d2$id,]
```

Output:

```
    id vals
2  222    2
5   56    5
6    7    6
7    8    7
10  12   10
11  13   11
12  14   12
```

Comment: thank you! can I use this peace of code in cases, when I have more than 2 tables to juxtopose? for example, ```d3 <- d1[d1$id %in% d2$id & d1$id %in% d4$id, ]```?

Comment: @k1rgas For sure you can but you can test using `&` and the operator `|` like `d3 <- d1[d1$id %in% d2$id | d1$id %in% d4$id, ]` because `|` means union. You can test both options but I believe `&` will remove the data as it looks for all conditions to be reached! Hoping that was clear!

Answer (score 3):

You may look for `semi_join`. It has join in it's name, but it won't merge both dataframes.

```
library(tidyverse)


semi_join(d1, d2, by = "id")

   id vals
1 222    2
2  56    5
3   7    6
4   8    7
5  12   10
6  13   11
7  14   12
```

Comment: thank you! your wonderful peace of code works nice, never knew about ```semi_join()```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:
**Option 1**
`d1[!d1$id%in%d2$id,]`
**Option 2**
`d1[is.na(match(d1$id,d2$id)),]`
**Option 3**
`library(dplyr) anti_join(d1, d2, by="id")`

Comment: could you, please, comment on ```anti_join()```?